# Probability - Change of variables using marginalization

Tags: probability

I was trying to get to the change of variables formula using marginalization. Suppose we have $y = g(x)$, so:

$$f_Y(y) = \int f_{Y,X}(y,x) dx = \int f_{Y}(y|x) f_{X}(x) dx = $$
$$= \int \delta(y - g(x)) f_X(x) dx = \int \delta(g^{-1}(y) - x) f_X(x) dx = $$
$$= f_X(g^{-1}(y))$$

Which is not the correct formula, obtained using the usual CDF technique:

$$f_Y(y) = \left|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)\right| f_X(g^{-1}(y))$$

What am I getting wrong? How can I obtain the correct formula using marginalization?

Comment: In fact, $\delta(y - g(x)) \neq \delta(g^{-1}(y) - x)$.

Comment: Even if $g$ is a bijection?